# UICollectionViewCell With Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView in Storyboard, in a UICollectionViewController. The UICollectionViewController is linked to my custom `class MasterViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate`, and it's delegate and datasource are linked in the storyboard to this class.

I have a prototype UICollectionViewCell in storyboard, with an identifier "MyCell", from my custom `class Cell: UICollectionViewCell`

In the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method, the app crash at the line : `let cell:Cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as Cell`

I don't find why. I haven't implemented the `registerClass:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:` method, and the identifier of the storyboard is exactly "MyCell", I checked many times, and the delegate and datasource are linked to the right class.

When the app crash, nothing is printed in the console, just "(lldb)"

Here's my code :

```
class MasterViewController: UICollectionViewController,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate {


var objects = [ObjectsEntry]()

@IBOutlet var flowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(collectionView!.bounds.width - 52, 151)

}



// MARK: - Collection View

override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return objects.count
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell:Cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as Cell

    return cell

}
```

Comment: Here is a walk through of getting a basic Collection View and Collection View Cell set up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31735228/how-to-make-a-simple-collection-view-with-swift

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. [Raywenderlich Swift manual](http://www.raywenderlich.com/78550/beginning-ios-collection-views-swift-part-1) helped me. I copying `MyCollectionViewController` here.

- Identifier must match in controller and Storyboard.
- Create custom `UICollectionViewCell` class.
- Set this `UICollectionViewCell` in Storyboard.
- Do not call `viewDidLoad()`.
- Do not call `registerClass:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:`
- Set cell item size with `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` in `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:`.

  ```
  import UIKit

  class MyCollectionViewController:
  UICollectionViewController,
  UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

  private let reuseIdentifier = "ApplesCell"

  // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

  override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return 1
  }

  override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
             cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
      let cell  = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as MyCollectionViewCell
      cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
      cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "red_apple")
      return cell
  }
  ```